# matlab 3d graph based on x,y,z data

Tags: matlab, graph, 3d

I'm trying to create a mesh-type plot to analyse the impact of centrifugation and time on the viability of bone cells. If my results are:

500g, 2min --> 0.12 /
500g, 10 min --> 0.00 /
4500g, 2 min --> 0.12 /
4500g, 10 min --> 0.10 /

, how would I plot this data in a 3D graph? I'm v. new to matlab - spent ~ 4 hours trying to figure this out. Would be useful to use this as a template for future work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,
W

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you're looking for

```
weight = [500, 4500];
time = [2;10];
results = [0.12, 0.12; 0, 0.10];

surf(weight, time, results)

xlabel('wieght')
ylabel('time')
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I just blindly copied the values without noticing the repeated values, **even though** I mentioned that is what the OP needs to be doing in my explanation on mesh plots. I've deleted my answer, and +1 to you :)

Comment: May the force be with you! = )